# No sound while "listening" to the radio

Tags: sound, streaming, mplayer, internet-radio

Mplayer opens a link and it seems to be running smoothly. The only problem is that there is no sound to listen to. Apart from this there are no problems with sound in system.

Comment: Can you provide an example of a link that you try?

Comment: Yes, of course: mplayer mms://stream.polskieradio.pl/program3

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I did some testing.
There is no problem with your ubuntu or mplayer.
The stream you mentioned just consists of silence.

if you want to doublecheck, try another stream like, for example, this one:

```
mplayer mms://a1075.l1062331074.c10623.g.lm.akamaistream.net/D/1075/10623/v0001/reflector:31074
```

Comment: Agreed. Even on a Fedora machine it does not work. A quick Google found [this](http://forums.screamer-radio.com/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=12292) though.

Answer (score 0):

The asx file for Polskie Radio Program III shows 3 URLs:

```
<ref href = "mms://stream.polskieradio.pl/program3">
<ref href = "rtsp://stream.polskieradio.pl/program3">
<ref href = "http://stream.polskieradio.pl/program3">
```

and certainly at the moment all 3 work for me with MPlayer, a slightly edited example using the http file:

```
andrew@skamandros~$ mplayer -quiet 'http://stream.polskieradio.pl/program3'
MPlayer SVN-r37183-4.8.2 (C) 2000-2014 MPlayer Team

Playing http://stream.polskieradio.pl/program3.
Resolving stream.polskieradio.pl for AF_INET6...
[...]

Cache size set to 185 KBytes
Cache fill: 18.05% (34013 bytes)   

ASF file format detected.
[asfheader] Audio stream found, -aid 1
==========================================================================
Trying to force audio codec driver family ffmpeg...
Opening audio decoder: [ffmpeg] FFmpeg/libavcodec audio decoders
libavcodec version 55.60.103 (internal)
AUDIO: 48000 Hz, 2 ch, floatle, 96.0 kbit/3.12% (ratio: 12000->384000)
Selected audio codec: [ffwmav2] afm: ffmpeg (DivX audio v2 (FFmpeg))
==========================================================================
AO: [alsa] 48000Hz 2ch floatle (4 bytes per sample)
Video: no video
Starting playback...
```

Perhaps try again and all will be well now...